# PrimeFaces Gmap updating

Tags: google-maps, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to use primafaces gmap.Also i need to add marker on the map.However i need only one marker on the map.So if selected marker needed to be changed i have to update the map.

I could not find a way for updating the map properly.I have tried this:

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialUpdateTarget("form:MapId");

When i try this, map is not coming to the page.

Another thing i tried as a solution is redirecting to the page.It works actually but validations have been a problem.

Any solutions to update gmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private void clearMap ( DefaultMapModel map)
{
    for (Marker marker : map.getMarkers()) {
        marker.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try addind an ajax element inside the gmap tag:

```
<p:gmap ...>
    <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{myBean.onMarkerSelect}" update=":form:MapId" />
</p:gmap>
```

Add this method to your managed bean (eg. myBean):

```
public void onMarkerSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event){
    Marker marker = (Marker)event.getOverlay();
}
```

Do what you want to do with the marker and the mapModel inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use javascript google maps api to set and update the marker.

Comment: can you help me how to use google maps api,any documentations?